# Bind to privileged ports with out administrator privilege, win-10/server-2016

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-10

Isn't there the concept of privileged ports in newer versions of windows ? I was able to bind to any privileged port from a non-admin logged in user. Is this normal behavior ?

Below are the steps I followed:

1. Logged in as non-admin user in Windows-server 2016.
2. Installed python
3. started the server on port 80 using `python -m
   SimpleHTTPServer 80`
4. Another user on the same system could
   access using `http://localhost`.

I was of the impression that to bind to privileged ports it would require Administrative privilege. Any comments anyone ?

Comment: On client versions of Windows, as best I can recall, you could always bind to well-known ports without admin privilege.  I'm not sure about Windows Server.

Comment: The behaviour is same in case of windows 2016 server also.